# How can I setup an SQLite database for serverless Cloud Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-lambda, sqlite, amazon-efs

I have some Serverless Lambda Functions and I would like to host an SQLite database with about a GB of data for free or very cheaply (1 USD per month).

My initial thought is to use Amazon Elastic File System or an EFS like service but I'm not sure it works like a normal file system. Also there might be syncing issues when the lambda function is destroyed. Can EFS be accessed from a different cloud provider e.g. heroku or firebase cloud functions? This [post](https://serverfault.com/q/823532/291866) mentions EFS does not have correct locking support for sqlite. Maybe I could use [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/)?

Any suggestions of what I could use?

I also found [glitch allows you to setup an sqlite database](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sqlite3-db?path=server.js:25:15) for free pretty easily but I don't want to be bound to the glitch ecosystem.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. I did a quick bit of reading. You could potentially use [this lambda layer](https://github.com/dschep/sqlite-lambda-layer), but I also read somewhere else you can't run more than one lambda concurrently. You should really use DynamoDB for this, it may even be free due to the free tier, if not it won't cost much. If you really need SQLite you may have to run a t3.nano with a small EBS volume, which costs about $5/month, and you have to maintain the server.

Comment: The only issue for me is that dynamo DB is not relational

Comment: This is true. Do you really need relational, or do you just not want to rewrite your app? If you need relational I think you need to increase your budget and go with RDS or something on an instance.